# How do I load PATH variables when starting node process with systemctl?

Tags: node.js, bash, webpack, aws-iot, systemctl

**Some background:**
I have a web application running on a robot. It's a web app - node.js for API/http server, React built with webpack on the front. It interfaces with AWS IoT core for running jobs, updates, etc. This part is all working fine. The application opens in Chrome in kiosk mode when the robot turns on. To do this, I have a systemctl service that runs the node script that starts everything.

**The issue**:
I have a job that I create in AWS IoT Core that my app is watching for. It's for software updates (particularly building the frontend of the application). The app realizes there's a new job to execute and downloads a file called deploy.sh and then tries to execute it by running `bash deploy.sh`. The connection with IoT is fine - it successfully downloads it and attempts to run it. The issue is that it fails to execute. Here's what the script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

APP_DIR=/homepath/to/the/app
GIT_URL=https://git/repo/link/to/project.git

# pull latest code
if [[ -e $APP_DIR ]]; then

    cd $APP_DIR
    git stash
    git pull $GIT_URL master
else
    git clone $GIT_URL $APP_DIR
    cd $APP_DIR
fi

# Install prod dependencies
yarn install --quiet --non-interactive > "/dev/null" 2>&1

# Build & Restart application
yarn build --quiet
```

The `git` commands work fine here and pull down the code. Here's the result:

```
Error: Command failed: bash deploy.sh
From https://git/repo/link/to/project.git
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
warning You are using Node "4.2.6" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
warning package.json: No license field
error Couldn't find the binary npm run webpack
```

I know the issue is because I am starting the node server with systemctl so it can't find all of the commands in the PATH because it work when I just start it like `node app.js`. It also gives me that error message about Node 4.2.6, so I KNOW it's not loading the correct one. I have `8.11.1` installed using nvm. Here's the scripts section from my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "build": "npm run webpack -- --env.mode production --env.presets clean"
}
```

The `env.mode production` is all stuff used by webpack and works.

**TL;DR**
When I run `yarn build` from my script, it can't find the webpack binary - in other words, when I run an npm script (webpack) from my package.json from a script that I downloaded during a node process that was started with systemctl - it can't resolve the paths.

**Things I've tried:**

- installing webpack globally
- using `./deploy.sh` instead of `bash deploy.sh`
- sourcing `.bashrc` in my script
- changing my package.json scripts to use absolute paths to the node_modules/.bin directory
- calling `bash deploy.sh` directly from command line - this works perfectly fine. It's only when I call it from the node process started with systemctl. If I start node by typing `node app.js`, then it works.

**My info:**

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
- Node: v8.11.1